# Data type incompatibility in vb.net , sqlcommand code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to create a login form for my sql database in vb.net. When I execute the program, I get this error:

> datatype text and text incompatible around equal to operator

My code:

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-56RQL1O\SQLEXPRESS; Database = student;user=tulsi;password=tulsi123;Integrated Security=true")
Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from student_table where Username = @username and Password = @password", connection)

command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.Text).Value = UsernameTextBox.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.Text).Value = PasswordTextBox.Text

Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

Dim table As New DataTable()

adapter.Fill(table)

If table.Rows.Count() <= 0 Then

    MessageBox.Show("Username Or Password Are Invalid")

Else

    MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully")

    Me.Hide()
    user_profile.Show()

End If
```

The error is occurring on this line of code:

```
adapter.Fill(table)
```

Comment: Yes they are in text datatype

Comment: This looks likes you're storing your passwords as plain text; I strongly recommend against that. Ideally you should be strong hashed and salted values.

Comment: I would recommend using `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UsernameTextBox.Text)` as the data type is taken care of for you.

Comment: @Jaberwocky - Actually that's not a good idea.  As ADO.Net might guess the wrong datatype which could result in the wrong indexes being chosen by the executing engine affecting performance.  See this:  [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I'm sure you're right.  Old habits die hard I guess.  It's even still recommended in the MSDN docs :P

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `Username` and `Password` columns are of type `text`, which cannot be compared.

The `text` type in SQL Server has been phased out in favor of `nvarchar`.  Change your columns to `nvarchar(x)` (where `x` is the max length you plan on supporting) and your comparisons will be fine.

Comment: Small correction: `text` has been replaced by `varchar` while `ntext` has been replaced by `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 0):

In your database, you have declared either username or password as `text`, which is inappropriate and in this case also causes the problem, because you cannot compare values against a `text`.

More suitable declaration would be `nvarchar(256)` for the password. If the username will store an email address or automatically generated user name, I would go for `varchar(256)`, otherwise go for `nvarchar(256)`.

Another reason you don't want to use `text` here, is because you cannot create indexes on them. And you need an index on the username in order to quickly validate the login attempt.

One last thing, consider declaring the password as `nvarchar(512) collate Latin1_General_BIN` in the table, and compare it in your command with `Password = @password collate Latin1_General_BIN`. That way, you are ensured to get case sensitive and accent sensitive password comparison, regardless of your database setting (which is case insensitive by default).